# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this is null"

Tags: vue.js

I'm having trouble when trying to add 1 when clicking a button in Vue

I have created a function sumar, I call it in the v-on assigned to the button, created the "contador"  but I have an error. It says this is null; I don't know why, as I have initialized the variable contador to 0 in the props.

```
<template>

<section  class="articulos b-flex b-flex-wrap b-flex-center b-flex-center-horizontal">

                <p>{{ contador }}</p>



        <article v-for="imagen in imagenes" :key="imagen.id">

            <figure class="contenedor-articulo">

                    <img :src="require(`@/assets/img/${imagen.url}`)" /> 

                        <figcaption>

                            <h3>{{imagen.nombre}}</h3>



                            <p>+ 0,50 €</p>

                            <button v-on:click="sumar"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>

                        </figcaption>

            </figure>

        </article>


    </section>


</template>

<script>

    export default {
  name: 'Articulos',

  props: {

      contador: 0
  },

  data() {

      return {
          imagenes: [

                {id:1, url:"apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg", nombre: "Ensalada quinoa chicken"},
                {id:2, url:"apeteat_2017__ensaladilla_rusa.jpg", nombre: "Ensaladilla rusa"},
                {id:3,url:"apeteat_2018_nigirimix.jpg", nombre: "Niguiri mix"},
                {id:4, url:"apeteat_2019_wrapcesar.jpg", nombre: "Wrap cesar"},
                {id:5, url:"apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg", nombre: "Ensalada quinoa chicken"},  
                {id:6, url:"apeteat_2018_nigirimix.jpg", nombre: "Niguiri mix"}

          ],

          sumar: function () {
        this.contador++ 
                }


            }
        }

}
</script>
```

I have the following error message:

Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this is null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the script, changed added to props to set default to zero, moved sumar to methods. Please check, this way it will work fine

```
 <script>

export default {
    name: 'Articulos',
    props: {
        contador: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
    },
  data() {
        return {
            imagenes: [
                {id:1, url:"apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg", nombre: "Ensalada quinoa chicken"},
                {id:2, url:"apeteat_2017__ensaladilla_rusa.jpg", nombre: "Ensaladilla rusa"},
                {id:3,url:"apeteat_2018_nigirimix.jpg", nombre: "Niguiri mix"},
                {id:4, url:"apeteat_2019_wrapcesar.jpg", nombre: "Wrap cesar"},
                {id:5, url:"apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg", nombre: "Ensalada quinoa chicken"},  
                {id:6, url:"apeteat_2018_nigirimix.jpg", nombre: "Niguiri mix"}
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sumar: function () {
                this.contador++ 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Vue automatically binds the `this` value for the functions in `methods` so that they can be safely invoked as event handlers. By defining your function in `data` you don't get this automatic binding.

Adding an event listener does something roughly equivalent to this:

```js
addEventListener('click', this.sumar)
```

The `this` binding is lost here. This may not be immediately obvious but once the function is passed to `addEventListener` the `this` is gone.

There are several solutions here. The simplest would be to move your function into the `methods` section.

```js
methods: {
  sumar () {
    this.contador++ 
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could use `bind` or grab an alias for `this` (i.e. `const that = this`) as a closure.

I would add that you shouldn't be trying to update the value of a prop from within your component. You'll find that Vue logs a warning message when you do. You should either emit an event so that the data's owner can update it or take a copy of the prop into local `data`. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow for more information.